# Laravel not passing query result from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel version 5.2

My controller file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\questions;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;

class Dashboard extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function fetchQuestions() {
        //
    }
    public function index(){
        $listQuestions=Auth::user()->questions()->pluck('question')->all();
        //dd($listQuestions);
        return view('forms.question',compact('listQuestions'));
    }
}
```

My views file

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($listQuestions as $q)
        <li>{{ $q }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
```

$listQuestions isnt getting passed to the view.
But on dd($listQuestions) from view & controller file, I get this

```
    array:2 [▼
  0 => "some question"
  1 => "another question"
]
```

It shows empty view page, no errors or output
What am I missing here?

Comment: I have done the same thing and it works. Maybe you can show dashboard.blade.php as well?

Answer (score 0):

[`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) method retrieves values by keys. You want to get a collection:

```
$listQuestions = Auth::user()->questions()->get();
```

`$q` is an object, so you need to get a property, i.e. `question`:

```
@foreach ($listQuestions as $q)
    <li>{{ $q->question }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: still no output

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri, if you put `{{ dd($q) }}` after `@foreach` clause, what do you see?

Comment: this `questions {#185 ▼
  #table: "questions"
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #hidden: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:4 [▼
    "question_id" => 8
    "people_id" => 2
    "question" => "some question"
    "created_at" => "2016-10-19"
  ]
  #original: array:4 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
....
}`

Comment: Ok, so my code above should show `some question` text.

Comment: I'm still getting an empty page

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a variable to a view like this

```
return view('forms.question')
     ->with('listQuestions' , $listQuestions)
```

Now i believe you're just passing the string 'listQuestions' over to the view, so it can't iterate over it. Hence the empty view.

Answer (score -1):

Change your

```
   return view('forms.question',compact('listQuestions'));
```

To

```
   return view('forms.question',['listQuestions'=> $listQuestions]);
```

That should work

Comment: This answer is quite useless, as these two code samples return the same thing. See the manual on compact(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Comment: @Jan Willems I am aware of this but compact function has some issues as I have had past experiences with it not to work but the other approach is a sure way of passing data